# xcode - automatic code refactoring tool

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a any code refactoring tool that can refactor predefined code. Like:

```
self = [super init];

if (self)
```

Change to:

```
if (self = [super init])
```

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a […] tool[…] are off-topic for Stack Overflow […]."

Comment: do you want to use a code beautifier or a code formatter?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I think code formatter is more appropriate. If I understand correctly, code beautifier will only change spaces and, alignment and newlines. It is not aware of context